# how to extract substring before a specified character (comma)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to extract everything before the ',' comma. and replace it with a  same name image. How do i do this in javascript or jquery? I tried this but not working for the first and the last string
 here is my codes:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function splitString(stringToSplit, separator) {
var arrayOfStrings = stringToSplit.split(separator);
document.write('<img src="/images/'+ arrayOfStrings.join('.png" /><img src="/images/') + '/>');
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div  class="slidepop">
<script> splitString(',brickfast,travel insurance,guide,sim cart,tour',',')</script>
</div>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `',brickfast......` or `'brickfast......` ???

Comment: Are you trying to have one `img` element per token in the `',brickfast,travel insurance...` string?

Comment: That's still going to be a code validation problem using `document.write` like that. You're going to need to change your coding practices, for sure.

Comment: @TrailMix yeah . like : brickfast.png and  travel insurance.png . i had this image with these names but it doesn't work for the last world and execute another null image for the first of string

Comment: What is before `,brickfast`? Looks like nothing to me.

Comment: @PranavCBalan ,brickfast ... i have a comma begining of my string

Comment: @PHPglue i have a comma at the begin of string

Comment: You just want to remove the first comma? `stringToSplit.replace(/^,/, '').split(separator);`.

Comment: @PranavCBalan cuz strings return like this of database

Comment: @inaz : then remove the first element from the array before joining `var arrayOfStrings = stringToSplit.split(separator);arrayOfStrings.shift();
document.write('<img src="/images/'+ arrayOfStrings.join('.png" /><img src="/images/') + '/>');`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you use a split method you get an array of strings in return. But you are directly joining the array with the html tags. You can try something like below in which I am joining the string at a particular index of the array of strings.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function splitString(stringToSplit, separator) {
var arrayOfStrings = stringToSplit.split(separator);
document.write('<img src="/images/'+ arrayOfStrings[1].join('.png" /><img src="/images/') + '/>');
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div  class="slidepop">
<script> splitString(',brickfast,travel insurance,guide,sim cart,tour',',')</script>
</div>   
</body>
</html>`
```

If you want to display all images in the array of strings, you can traverse through all array like this.

```
    <html>
        <head>
        <script>
        function splitString(stringToSplit, separator) {
        var arrayOfStrings = stringToSplit.split(separator);

        var imagesHtml = '';
        for(var i = 0; i < arrayOfStrings.length; i++){
            if(arrayOfStrings[i] !== ''){
               imagesHtml = imagesHtml + '<img src="/images/' + arrayOfStrings[i] + '.png" />'
            }
        }
        var newDiv = $("<div></div>");
        newDiv.append(imagesHtml);
        $(".slidepop").append(newDiv);
}
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div  class="slidepop">
        <script> splitString(',brickfast,travel insurance,guide,sim cart,tour',',')</script>
        </div>   
        </body>
        </html>`
```

Comment: thank u but the new code of u works only for the first string.

Comment: Really Sorry but forgot to replace the index number with the iterator 'i'
Should work fine now

Comment: can u tell me what was my problem plz ?

Comment: You were using array.join method with the raw html of image tag. and that method just put the joining string with the array as a new index.
When you splitted the string, it gave you an array of strings. But as your first string was null (no string before first comma) so It was not picking any image name from that index.
So I put a check to see if the string is empty string or not. If not, then it should load an image with that name. Otherwise it moves to next index of the array

Comment: when i put this code in my page my page work correct but after 2s  all of my page disappear and shows only the result of my function. like a redirect .

Comment: Its because you are directly writing to document. 
If you want to add in the div that has class "slidepop" then I have updated the answer according to that please check

Comment: 5 world ? sorry I didn't get u

Comment: yes i add other words to my string but it returns only 5 word of begin and replace it with image

Comment: just change my string to         <script> splitString(',brickfast,travel insurance,guide,sim cart,tour,visa,transfer,lunch',',')</script>

Comment: It is working fine with me and it is showing resource not available on 8 images (same count as strings in array)

Comment: yeah it works . but i have 2 div with class: slidepop with different string. but it only shows the first div content to all divs         <div  class="slidepop">
        <script> splitString(',tour,transfer,brickfast,guide',',')</script>
        </div>   
        
         <div class="slidepop">
        <script> splitString(',tour,transfer,brickfast,guide,city guid , climbing',',')</script>
        </div>

Comment: That is because $('.slidepop').html(string) adds the html string to all the divs with class slidepop

Comment: what shoud i do to show the correct sting of each array inside each class? thank u for ur guide

Comment: You can put different class names on both divs and pass the class name of the div inside splitString function. I have edited my answer to accept a third parameter as class name. it will add the passed string (images) in the class name passed in function.

Comment: I have edited the answer. It will now create a div element dynamically and add all images passed in it and then add this div inside the div with class name slidepop.
But you have to pass all scripts inside one div with class name slidepop
<div  class="slidepop">
        <script> splitString(',brickfast,travel insurance,guide,sim cart,tour',',')</script>
<script> splitString(',brickfast2,travel insurance2,guide2,sim2 cart2,tour2',',')</script>
        </div>

Comment: But this class(slidepop) will be repeatable in seprate boxes i can't pass all scripts inside one div

Comment: Please post another question and we will take it from there. This is not the best way to handle the problem

Answer (score 0):

### you need to apply loop as :

```
for(var i = 0; i < arrayOfStrings.length; i++){

            if(arrayOfStrings[i] !== ''){

               document.write('<img src="/images/'+ arrayOfStrings[i].join('.png" /><img src="/images/') + '/>');

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Same basic premise as @Hemanshi karelia, but instead of using document.write, I suggest creating a string from the image elements and then when all elements have been added to this image string - adding it to the div using jquery's .html(). This is advantageous because it only manipulates the DOM at the end, when all of the image elements have been built and passed into the image string that is then passed into the div, rather than all the other posted answers which alter the DOM on each iteration.

```js
splitString('brickfast,travel insurance,guide,sim cart,tour');

function splitString(stringTotal) {
  var stringPortions = stringTotal.split(",");
  var imageString="";
     for(i = 0; i < stringPortions.length; i++){
       imageString += "<img src='/images/" + stringPortions[i] +".png'/>";
       }
  $('.slidepop').html(imageString);
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div  class="slidepop"></div>
```

Comment: For your information, first he wanted to solve the actual problem instead looking at the performance issue first. That takes his eyes away from actual problem. No answer is perfect. It can always get better by editing rather than down voting and putting your separate answer as the correct one. We are here to help not proving who is wrong an right

Comment: @Umair Farooq  - I didn't downvote your answer. I just offered a different approach and pointed out a benefit that might be of benefit. Wasn't saying yours was wrong at all - just offering a different option. And looking at your answer - it seems as you have edited the second portion to be like my option. So it was a valid suggestion that I made. If I was to comment on your, I would suggest loading the jQuery library since the option i suggested and you have implemented requires it. And I would suggest wrapping the jQuery portion in a $(document).ready({}) wrapper. But thats just a suggestion.

Comment: Sorry I thought u down-voted my answer. Yes you made the right approach I was just saying rather than providing an optimized solution at the first time, the solution should be optimized step by step. In this way the person asking question learn more because he won't care about the optimization unless he is stuck in some problem due to that. Maybe my thinking is wrong. So again sorry for thinking u down-voted my answer

Comment: @Umair Farooq - no worries. I do think that raises a good point though - If I downvote an answer I should havethe balls tosay hat I did it - so Stack Overflow should implement a feature of logging the id of the downvoters (and the upvoters) . Just because I posted a different answer and you happened to be downvoted led you to think i had done it. If there was some mechanism to view the downvoters names - it would have alleviated that.

Comment: Yes that creates a unwanted hatred among the users because there are a lot of users and posting of different answer and down-voting happens at the same time. And I am sure if it happened with us, it must had happened with many others.